# CodePen Java Script coding assistance

Tags: javascript, colors, codepen

I am working on a school project and i need some help. I have made this drawing game on CodePen.com and i need some help with the java script. I will send a link so you can look at it. So far on the bottom we have different colors. and we need the brush (the mouse) to be able to click on a color and then draw with it. Right now we only have it drawing in black. we don’t know how to make it vice versa when you click on a color. here is the link

codepen.io/bturner5/pen/zYNMjzY

If you find a way just answer it back. or type it in the code and save it and send the link back

Comment: Hey Josh, I'm sure you really needed the help on your project but in the future try to resolve the issue on yourself first, and reach the community only after failing. And if possible let us know what you've tried before so that we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delcare a variable to hold the `color`, you can default it to 'black'
2. Addadd an event listener to each of the colors to set the `color` variable, for instance

```js
document.querySelector('.red').addEventListener('click', () => color = 'red')
```

3. In your `drawLine` event refer to color instead of using `context.strokeStyle: 'black'`

```js
function drawLine(context, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  context.beginPath();
  // context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  // context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.strokeStyle = color; // use the variable color instead.
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.moveTo(x1, y1);
  context.lineTo(x2, y2);
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
}
```